# lateinit property fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin

when i try to change orientation of the display
it will show this error "lateinit property fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized"

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    internal lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>
    internal lateinit var mainMenuPagerAdapter: MainMenuPagerAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mainMenuPagerAdapter = MainMenuPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        setUpMainMenuPagerAdapter()
    }

    override fun onFragmentAttached() {
    }

    override fun onFragmentDetached(tag: String) {
    }

    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment>? {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

    private fun setUpMainMenuPagerAdapter() {
        mainMenuPagerAdapter.count = 1
        mainMenuViewPager.adapter = mainMenuPagerAdapter
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.my_account).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_person_white_24dp))
        mainMenuViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = tabLayout.tabCount;
        mainMenuViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {
                mainMenuViewPager.currentItem = tab.position
            }
            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab) {}
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, attach the code of BaseActivity

Comment: hi sorry, i try to edit the code but can't, so i put in the answer @IlyaTretyakov

Answer (score 0):

I had same crash when rotating screen, I was calling  AndroidInjection.inject(this) after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState).

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       ...
    }
```

After this no crash. It may help.

Answer (score -1):

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MVPView, BaseFragment.CallBack {

    private var progressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        performDI()
    }

    override fun hideProgress() {
        progressDialog?.let { if (it.isShowing) it.cancel() }
    }

    override fun showProgress() {
        hideProgress()
        progressDialog = CommonUtil.showLoadingDialog(this)
    }

    private fun performDI() = AndroidInjection.inject(this)

}
```

this is my `BaseActivity.ky`

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: i try to edit in the original question, but i can't add more code in there, i don't know why.